# Javascript Asynchronous Return Value

Tags: javascript, scope

Just as I thought I understood JS scope...

Take this code:

```
function init() {

    var page;
    var pageName = $('body').data('page');

    switch(pageName) {

        // (there are more switch cases here normally...)                   

        case 'pSearchLatest':
           require(['searchresults'], function (SearchResults) {
               page = new SearchResults().init();
               console.log(page); // <- shows the object!
           });

        default:
           break;

     }

     console.log(page); // <- undefined
     return page;

}
```

See the console log comments. Why is the second returning `undefined` when the `var page` is declared outside of the scope of the switch statement?

**EDIT**

So I mistakenly thought this was a scope issue but it's down to the asynchronous nature of AMD.

How can I return the value of page in the require scope in the same method without a while loop checking for undefined?

**EDIT 2**

I did it like this:

```
function init(callback) {

   case 'pSearchLatest':
      require(['searchresults'], function (SearchResults) {
          page = new SearchResults().init();
          callback(page)
      });
}
```

and in my page that calls the wrapping init() method:

```
new PageController().init(function(asyncViewController) {
   App.view = asyncViewController;
});
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/710446) -- please read that extremely helpful Q&A. The issue is not a scope issue, it's a timing issue. The callback has *not yet run* when the bottom `log` runs. The callback to `require` runs **last**, *after* `init` has terminated.

Comment: What do you expect it to return?

Comment: The require call is async

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did understand scope correctly. The code in that inner function does indeed assign to the variable in the outer scope.

What you did not understand is asynchronous behaviour. The `require` function takes a callback function which will be invoked somewhen in the future - when the requested module is available. Yet, it does immediately return and control flow will lead to the `console.log` statement, which does print `undefined` - which is the value the `page` variable has *at that time*.

You should be able to recognise that since the `undefined` is logged *first*, and the log statement in the callback (with the object) executes *later*, even though it comes above in the code.

Comment: Ah of course! ASYNCHRONOUS module definition. Duh. Thanks, will accept in 9 minutes :D.

Comment: eurgh, how do I return page in that init method? I guess I could do a while(page==undefined) thing but that's disgusting right?

Comment: @AdamWaite `while(page==undefined)` will *not* work, because JS is single-threaded. Set the scene: your callback is waiting for its time to fire, and the thread is busy looping. One day, the callback fires; it comes up to the thread and says "I'm ready to run now!" and thread says, "Sorry, not now, I'm too busy running this loop checking the value of `page`; you can run when it's done." The callback pleads, "But I'm the one that's suppose to *set* `page` for you! Can't you schedule me at all?" to which the thread replies, "Sorry, rules are rules! Guess I'll just run this loop forever, then!"

Comment: ha yeh, I'm used to writing in Objective-C and Ruby so Javascript always blows my mind a bit :D. I think I cracked it though, see my update.

Answer (score 2):

`require` is asynchronous, therefore your function did exit first and then processed callback function.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible reasons... you didnt match the case. or the callback where the assignment of the value to `page` happens hasnt been executed yet. Im guessing its the latter since it would be readily apparent if you `case` was failing. Look into the documentation for whatever AMD library youre using and see how the execution of the function(s) passed to `require` are executed.

Also as a generaly rule try to avoid returning values determined by asynchronous calls like this. Instead use some kind of Observer pattern to subscribe to a particular event that can be triggered from different places.